# IntegrityError at /save-comment/

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I created an opinion platform where the user can put the stars and give their opinion in comments, but when he wants to do it I always get an error.

Here is the error that appears all the time:

```
IntegrityError at /save-comment/

(1048, "Le champ 'concours_id' ne peut être vide (null)") concours.views.save_comment
.utilisateur}"
```

Code:

```
class AvisConcours(models.Model):
    concours = models.ForeignKey('concours.Concours', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='avis_concours')
    note = models.ManyToManyField('concours.Note', related_name='avis_note', blank=True,)
    commentaire = models.TextField(blank=True)
    utilisateur = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Avis de concours"
        verbose_name_plural = "Avis de concours"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.concours}" + " - " + f"{self.utilisateur}"
```

```
def save_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        commentaire = request.POST.get('commentaire')
        concours_id = request.POST.get('concours')
        utilisateur = request.user

        notes_to_create = []
        for note_type in NoteType.objects.all():
            rating_value = request.POST.get(f'rating_{note_type.id}')
            if rating_value is not None:  # Only create notes for non-empty ratings
                notes_to_create.append(Note(note_type=note_type, valeur=rating_value))

        # Save bulk Note
        created_notes = Note.objects.bulk_create(notes_to_create)

        # Save AvisConcours and link notes
        avis_concours = AvisConcours.objects.create(
            concours_id=concours_id,
            commentaire=commentaire,
            utilisateur=utilisateur
        )

        avis_concours.note.set(created_notes)  # Use set() to set ManyToManyField directly

        return redirect('merci_commentaire')

        # return redirect('merci_commentaire')
    return render(request, "page_commentaire.html")
```

```
  <div class="col-lg-8 ps-xxl-5 mt-5">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div class="give-rating-area mb-5">
                        <form method="post" action="/save-comment/"> {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="concours" value="{{concours.id}}">
                            <!-- Début:: Utilisateur connecté -->
                            <div class="give-rating-person">
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                <div class="thumb" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; border-radius: 50%; overflow: hidden;">
                                    {% if user.profile_image %}
                                    <img src="{{ user.profile_image.url }}" alt="{{ user.full_name }}'s profile image" style="width: 80%; height: 80%; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 80%;">
                                    {% else %}
                                    <img src="{% static 'images/avatar.jpg' %}" alt="Default profile image" style="width: 80%; height: 80%; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 80%;">
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="content">
                                    <h6>{{ user.full_name }}</h6>
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            
                            <!-- Début:: Utilisateur connecté -->

                            <br><br>
                            {% for note_type in note_types %}

                            <div class="give-rating-person">
                          
                              <div class="content">
                                <h6>{{ note_type.nom }}</h6>
                              </div>
                          
                              <div class='give-rating'>
                          
                                {% for i in "12345" reversed %}
                                  <span>
                                    <input id='str{{ i }}_{{ note_type.id }}' 
                                           name='rating_{{ note_type.id }}'
                                           type='radio' value='{{ i }}'>
                                    <label for='str{{ i }}_{{ note_type.id }}'>
                                      <i class="la la-star fa-sm"></i>
                                    </label>
                                  </span>
                                {% endfor %}
                                
                              </div>
                          
                            </div>
                          
                          {% endfor %}


                            <div class="mt-4">
                                    <textarea name="commentaire" class="form--control"
                                              placeholder="Ecrivez votre commentaire" required>
                                    </textarea>

                                <div class="text-end">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--base submitBtn">Soumettre
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    <div class="give-rating-area mb-5">
                        <p class="text-center">Veuillez vous <a href="{% url 'connexion' %}"
                            class=" text--base">connecter</a> d'abord pour soumettre votre avis. </p>                            </div>
                    <div class="mt-3">
                        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    
                    <div class="customer-review-wrapper">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="pagination justify-content-end me-3">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="review-block">
                            {% if avis_concours.exists %}
                            {% for avis in avis_concours %}
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="single-slide" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                                        <div class="review-card">
                                            <div class="give-rating-person">
                                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                                    <div class="thumb" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 50%; margin-right: 10px;">
                                                        <img src="{% if user.profile_image %}{{ user.profile_image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'images/avatar.jpg' %}{% endif %}" alt="Image de l'utilisateur" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        <h6>{{ user.full_name }}</h6>
                                                        <h6>  <p class="fs--14px mt-1">Concours commenté : <span class="text--base"><strong>{{ avis.concours.nom }}</strong></span></p>
                                                        </h6>
                                                    </div>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </div>
                                            <hr>

                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="review-card__ratings text--base">
                                                    <div class="review-card__ratings-text">
                                                        <h6>Note globlale de l'utilisateur</h6>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="review-card__ratings-stars">
                                                        <!-- Utilisez le filtre de modèle "rating_stars" pour afficher la moyenne des notes sous forme d'étoiles -->
                                                        <p class="fs--30px text-muted"> <span
                                                                style="font-weight: bold; font-size:30px"> {{ avis.average_rating }}/5</span>
                                                            Basé sur les notes detaillés

                                                        </p>
                                                        {{ avis.average_rating|rating_stars|safe }}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr>

                                            <h6>Notes detaillés de l'utilisateur</h6>

                                            <div class="row">
                                                {% if avis.note.exists %}
                                                {% for note in avis.note.all %}
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="review-card__ratings text--base">
                                                        <div class="review-card__ratings-text">
                                                            <p>{{note.note_type.nom}}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        {{ note.valeur|rating_stars|safe }}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                                {% else %}
                                                <div class="customer-review d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                    <h5>Aucun avis pour le moment !</h5>
                                                </div>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </div>
                                            <hr>
                                            <h5>Commentaire de l'utilisateur</h5>
                                            <p class="review-card__des">
                                                {{avis.commentaire}}
                                            </p>

                                            <p class="review-card__date">{{ avis.date }}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="customer-review d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <h5>Aucun avis pour le moment !</h5>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
```

Comment: Paste the error

Comment: IntegrityError at /save-comment/

(1048, "Le champ 'concours_id' ne peut être vide (null)") concours.views.save_comment .utilisateur}"```

Comment: When you get the `concours_id` from the request.POST, it will be a string. Try casting it to `int` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

My french is not too good, but I am pretty sure it has to do with the following block:

```
        # Save AvisConcours and link notes
        avis_concours = AvisConcours.objects.create(
            concours_id=concours_id, # This id is probably null, or None
            ...
        )
```

Print out the ID and check! :)

If not specified, fields will always be non-nullable. (concours foreign key)

Comment: yes but the problem is still there

Comment: Is it supposed to be null? I told you the solution. If not specified, fields will always be non nullable.